# single band .tif image is distorted when loaded in java

Tags: java, imaging

When using ImageIO.read() on a .tif image the pixel intensity values are being distorted.  I believe this is probably due to it being loaded as an rgb which results in vastly different pixel intensities.  Is there any way around this? or any other library that allows the import of single banded .tif images?

the images below demonstrate the issue that is occurring.  [This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af1HL.jpg), The left image is the correct pixel values loaded through imageJ and check again through loading it in matlab and the right is the result of viewing the image through a method in eclipse (also checked in other ide's though).

```html
  JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
  int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
  File file = null;
  if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
  }
  BufferedImage image = null;
  try {
   image = ImageIO.read(file);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
```

The intensity values are very important so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your images are missing and so is the code you are using to load the image. If you provide us with both there's a chance we can help

Comment: I'm not really sure what code would be useful tbh as its simply using the ImageIO.read method that is the issue and then displaying it simply through a jframe

Comment: Without code or source images, your question will be near impossible to answer. If you want people to make an effort for you, make an effort for them as well.

Comment: due to the fact that I have 0 rep i cannot post the pictures in line so there is a link to the picture included.  I have added the code into the original post